# array type has incomplete element type adjacency

Tags: c, arrays, adjacency-matrix

I got some homework and need to write a program wich given a matrix represents an adjacency.
The user need to put the matrix in and the index and the program returns true if there is a path between the two values of the indexes.
for example

```
0 1 2 3 4
1 0 1 0 0
2 0 0 1 0
3 0 0 0 0
4 0 0 0 0
```

If the user provides this matrix (without the indexes numbers) and gives the value 3,1 then it returns true because 3 is a son of 2 and 2 is a son of one. But if the user gives the value 4,1 it returns false.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define N 11
#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0


int path(long int [][20] A, int u, int v)
{
    if(u == 0 && A[u][v] == TRUE)
        return TRUE;

    if(u == 0 && A[u][v] == FALSE)
        return FALSE;

    if(A[u][v] == FALSE)
        return path(A, u--, v);

    else if(A[u][v] == TRUE)
        return path(A, N, u);
}

int main()
{
    int arr[11][11]  = {{0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                        {0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0},
                        {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0},
                        {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
                        {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                        {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                        {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                        {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                        {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                        {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                        {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}};

    return path(arr,1,8);
    return 0;
}
```

when I try to run it on gcc it returns:

> adjacency.c:8:26: error: expected ‘;’, ‘,’ or ‘)’ before ‘A’
>     adjacency.c: In function ‘main’:
>    adjacency.c:30:1: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘path’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]

Can enybody please tell me why? And if my program even works??
Thanks guys

Comment: `long int [][20] A` -> `int A[][11]`

Comment: FYI, `return 0;` will never execute

Comment: `return path(A, N, u);` cause the outside array bounds

Answer (score 1):

The function prototypes doesn't match the array size.

Try changing

```
int path(long int [][20] A, int u, int v)
```

into

```
int path(long int A[][11], int u, int v)   // Move A
```

and in main change

```
 int arr[11][11]
```

to

```
 long int arr[11][11]
```

or drop the long in the function

```
int path(int A[][11], int u, int v)
```

BTW:

```
return path(A, N, u);
```

is probably bad as N=11. You will index outside the array.

Maybe you want

```
return path(A, N-1, u);
```

instead to avoid indexing the array out of range.

**IMPORTANT:**

```
return path(A, u--, v);
```

probably needs to be:

```
return path(A, --u, v);
```

Because u-- is a post-decrement. You'll have an endless loop calling path(..) again and again with the same values.

You want it to decrement before the function call. So use --u as it is a pre-decrement.

Comment: @user4831626 - A  need to be before the [][11]

Comment: well im stating to loose my mind :( did everything you said and it steel not working. anyone has an idea how to do it?

Comment: @user4831626  I'm not sure what you want your code to do but at least it can compile with the changed proposed.

Comment: yeah it can. but now im getting  "segmentation fault (core dumped)" when triying to exacute. the program needs to receive two numbers for example 1, 8 and to return if 8 has a direct path to 1. think about it like a tree